# Set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' with browser sync in grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, browser-sync

I'm trying to set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to * with browser sync in grunt.

This is what I'm trying but I still get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" message in my console.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');

    grunt.initConfig({
        browserSync: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    server: {
                        baseDir: './',
                        middleware: function (req, res, next) {
                            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                            next();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // define default task
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['browserSync']);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried do the same with Gulp, but couldn't do that.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

This plugin helped me, maybe You will find it useful.